# How could I efficiently get the closest points on the surface of my model?

Tags: python, plotly

I am plotting a 3d mesh in Plotly. I load an STL file using numpy-stl, and break it up to plot it from there. I am hoping to create a warming effect for beacons that I hardcoded in. So, the closer that beacon is to the surface of the mesh, the warmer the surrounding area is. (Next step after that would be to scale the size of that warming effect to the magnitude of the beacon's temp)

The below code is what I put together so far. The reason I do not like it, even if I could get it to function fully, is that it relies on the vertices to determine how close the given beacon is to the surface, not the surface itself. So the warming effect will always be centered at a vertex, which can give some weird results.

How could I efficiently get the closest points (to the beacons in my image) on the surface of my model?

```
def stl2mesh3d(stl_mesh):
    # stl_mesh is read by numpy-stl from a stl file; it is  an array of faces/triangles (i.e. three 3d points) 
    # this function extracts the unique vertices and the lists I, J, K to define a Plotly mesh3d
    p, q, r = stl_mesh.vectors.shape #(p, 3, 3)
    # the array stl_mesh.vectors.reshape(p*q, r) can contain multiple copies of the same vertex;
    # extract unique vertices from all mesh triangles
    vertices, ixr = np.unique(stl_mesh.vectors.reshape(p*q, r), return_inverse=True, axis=0)
    I = np.take(ixr, [3*k for k in range(p)])
    J = np.take(ixr, [3*k+1 for k in range(p)])
    K = np.take(ixr, [3*k+2 for k in range(p)])
    return vertices, I, J, K

my_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('AT&T Building.stl')

# To explain what I, J, K are:
# A vector of vertex indices, i.e. integer values between 0 and the length of the vertex vectors, 
# representing the “first” vertex of a triangle. For example, {i[m], j[m], k[m]} together represent
# face m (triangle m) in the mesh, where i[m] = n points to the triplet {x[n], y[n], z[n]} in the 
# vertex arrays. Therefore, each element in i represents a point in space, which is the first vertex of a triangle.

vertices, I, J, K = stl2mesh3d(my_mesh)
x, y, z = vertices.T

# [x,y,z,temp]
beacons = [[-10,10,20,50],[-20,20,60,50]]
df_beacons = pd.DataFrame (beacons, columns = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'temp'])
intensity = np.full(x.size, 1000)

# find min of abs(vertex_xyz - point_xyz) for each xyz
# this sets intensity as, the closer your are to the point, the warmer you are (closer == smaller value)
for beacon in beacons:
    for idx in range(0,intensity.size):
        intensity[idx] = min(abs(x[idx] - beacon[0]) + abs(y[idx]-beacon[1]) + abs(z[idx]-beacon[2]), intensity[idx])
intensity[intensity == 1000] = 0

toAdd = np.empty(I.size - x.size, dtype=None)
x = np.concatenate((x, toAdd))
y = np.concatenate((y, toAdd))
z = np.concatenate((z, toAdd))
intensity = np.concatenate((intensity, toAdd))
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z':z, 'I':I, 'J':J, 'K':K, 'intensity':intensity})

# https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Mesh3d.html
mesh3D = go.Mesh3d(
    x=df.x,
    y=df.y,
    z=df.z, 
    i=df.I, 
    j=df.J, 
    k=df.K, 
    name = "mesh",
    showscale=True,
    showlegend = True,
#     colorscale=[[0, '#e5dee5'], [1, 'red']], 
    colorscale = "thermal",
    colorbar_x=-0.1,
    intensity=df.intensity,
    flatshading=True,
    lighting=dict(
        ambient= 0.18,
        diffuse= 1,
        fresnel=  .1,
        specular= 1,
        roughness= .1,
        facenormalsepsilon=0
    ),
    lightposition=dict(
        x=3000,
        y=3000,
        z=10000
    )
)
```

[image: Model]

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the SciPy function KDTree, which supports N-dimensional point sorting. I've also included a link to some examples which may be useful - good luck!

[SciPy KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

[Examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)